# Create SQL table using full DATE

Tags: php, sql, date

I'm currently creating a database and I'm facing a little issue. I want to add a column containing the date. So I create it like this :

```
create table comments
(
    id serial not null,
    id_user integer not null,
    content text not null,
    id_thread integer not null,
    date date default now()
);
```

The problem is that the date is just like this : 14-06-2017 and I want to have the hour of the creation.

How I can do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `date datetime default now()`

Comment: Consider using `datetime` or `timestamp` instead of plain `date`.

Comment: use datetime. `date datetime default now()`

Comment: Also consider renaming attribute `date`, date is a reserved keyword, things are easier if you name it differently.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot :)